# IE10: border ignores element's z-index

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

So there is a problem: elements' border has the highest z-order

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: absolute;
}
.el {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 8;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border: #000 5px solid;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.el:hover {
    background-color: #F00;
}
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
</style>
```

`.el` has z-index lower than `.overlay` has so it should not react on hover.
But if I move mouse across the `.el`'s borders it becomes red.
Does anybody know is this specific for IE10 only?
And are there any workarounds to force `.el` be completely below than `.overlay`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG. accidentally I've found workaround for this. If we use any background-color in `.overlay` and set very small opacity than `.el`'s borders stops to react on mouse over.

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: absolute;
}
.el {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 8;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border: #000 5px solid;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.el:hover {
    background-color: #F00;
}
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.01;
}
```

Actually it works even with opacity: 0; in my IE10

Answer (score 0):

The z-index should be higher not lower , try changing the values :

http://jsfiddle.net/jJ7M7/

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: absolute;
}
.el {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border: #000 5px solid;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.el:hover {
    background-color: #F00;
}
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for complex explanation.
.overlay SHOULD BE higher than .el
And it is higher. Except .el's border.